# how to send event to main thread in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I'm using threading and I want to start a tkinter loop within a secondary thread.

I've learnt that this causes troubles, and that tkinter should be run always in the main thread.

I wonder if it is possible to send ann event to the main thread from a secondary thread.

I've come with a solution like this, which involves sending a signal from the secondary thread setting a main class-variable, as a condition to run the code I want to be run in the main thread:

```
import threading as th
import tkinter as tk

class Interfaz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock=False
        th.Thread(name='main_th',target=main).start()
        while True:
            if self.lock==False:
                if 'main_th' not in [t.getName() for t in th.enumerate()]:
                    th.Thread(name='main_th',target=main).start()
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                self.stkinter()
  
    def main(self):
        if user_click() == True:
            self.lock==True
            #send_tkinter_to_main_thread()...
        else:
            show_or_update_interfaz()
            do_something_else()
    def stkinter(self):
        self.master=tk.Tk()
        tk.Button(self.master,command=self.Done).grid()
        self.master.mainloop()
    def Done(self):
        self.master.destroy()
        self.lock=False
```

What I would like to do is to excecute 'stkinter' from 'main', sending it to the main thread... is that possible?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the `event_generate` method?

Comment: @BryanOakley I did but honestly I couldn't follow it... (not an engineer here)